# parameters in sql fragment substitute error

Tags: mybatis

I write a sql fragment, like this:

```
<sql id="day">
        <choose>
            <when test="${property} == 'day'">
                substring(datachange_createtime, 1, 10)
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                ${property}
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
</sql>
```

and include this sql like this:

```
select * from my_table
        <if test="groupBy != null">
            group by
            <foreach collection="groupBy" item="groupByAttr" separator=",">
                <include refid="day">
                    <property name="property" value="groupByAttr"/>
                </include>
            </foreach>
        </if>
```

But I got an error, mybatis didn't substitute `property` with a real parameter, but with `groupByAttr`. The result sql is like:

```
   select * from my_table group by groupByAttr
```

In the otherwise clause, if I replace `${property}` with `#{${property}}`, The result sql becomes:

```
   select * from my_table group by ?
```

It is indeed correct, but for some reasons, I don't want a prepared sql.

I think the problem is the behavior of substitution in `test` and `otherwise` clauses is different.
Is the a bug, or just some mistakes I took? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

You need to change the `<include />` as follows.

```xml
<sql id="day">
  <choose>
    <when test="${property} == 'day'">
      substring(datachange_createtime, 1, 10)
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      \\${${property}}
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
</sql>
```

Long answer:

With your original code, the statement will look as follows after the `<include />` substitution.

```xml
select * from my_table
<if test="groupBy != null">
  group by
  <foreach collection="groupBy" item="groupByAttr" separator=",">
    <choose>
      <when test="groupByAttr == 'day'">
        substring(datachange_createtime, 1, 10)
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        groupByAttr
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
  </foreach>
</if>
```

As you can see, `<when />` is OK, but `<otherwise />` is not.
`<otherwise />` should look like this:

```xml
<otherwise>
  ${groupByAttr}
</otherwise>
```

In the expression in the short answer `\\${${property}}`, the first two backslashes is the escape syntax which avoids the outer `${}` from being treated as a variable.

Note that `#{groupByAttr}` does not work here because, in `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, a placeholder `?` is not allowed for a table/column name.
Please see the [wiki page](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the details.